# Open Street Map working offline android

Tags: android, android-maps, osmdroid, openstreetmap, android-maps-v2

I am a newbie to Open Street Map. I made some research and found that we can download and store the map into a folder. But i didn't find any tutorial or sample that provides offline Open Street Map. Can someone provide a step by step tutorial, a guide to implement offline open street map please. I am following this example http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2012/06/example-of-implementing-openstreetmap.html but now i want to make it available when there is no connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like in the tutorial you mentionned you can use osmdroid library:
https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/

There's a good explanation of how osmdroid works with offline maps here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8286276/891479

Use MapTileProviderBasic in your app.
Some examples here:
http://www.androidadb.com/class/ma/MapTileProviderBasic.html

To generate your offline maps in osmdroid format use Mobile Atlas Creator:
http://mobac.sourceforge.net/

You can choose the source of the maps and the output format. Once generated, put your maps atlas in zip format into your "/osmdroid/map" directory.

Hope it will help!

Comment: Hi @resus,... i just found out that Google Earth / Maps options have been removed from the Mobile Atlas Creator functions? If that's the case... how could I create the map of my area that supported to be read by osmdroid?

Comment: Google maps are probably not present for licensing reason, you can use openstreet maps sources for offline maps.

Answer (score 4):

I have found this [tutorial](http://www.haakseth.com/?p=30) that explains all things you need step by step.

In brief:

1- You must download map tiles using [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/). I have explained the steps [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32164040/2101822)

2- Move the resulting zip-file to /mnt/sdcard/osmdroid/ on your device.

3- Adding [osmdroid-android-XXX.jar](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/Downloads) and [slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar](http://www.slf4j.org/android/) into build path your project

4- Adding MapView: You can add a MapView to your xml layout

```
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tilesource="Mapnik"
    />
```

Or create a MapView programmatically:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    mResourceProxy = new ResourceProxyImpl(inflater.getContext().getApplicationContext());
    mMapView = new MapView(inflater.getContext(), 256, mResourceProxy);
    return mMapView;
}
```

Hope it Helps ;)

Comment: Mobile Atlas Creator is Blocked now. What to do now

Answer (score 0):

MOBAC(Mobile Atlas Creator) is blocked now for using OSM
You can see [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Blocked_applications)