# Android offline map implementation

Tags: android, sqlite, openstreetmap

I need to implement offline map in my app.I have googled a lot but didnt get any code for that. For instance open street map, Once we downloaded the map only we can able to show them in a map. but is also lacking with zoom in and zoom out capability.
If anyone know any good tutorial to show offline map dynamic downloading. If am specifying any country code, it need to download the whole map.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the Open Map Street offline.
here you will find some information and code.

[Open Street Map working offline android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794705/open-street-map-working-offline-android)

Comment: You should be aware that OSM now block access via the MOBAC application, as it hammers their servers too hard.

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenStreetMap wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/) has a really large list of [software for Android capable of displaying an OSM map](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android#Map_display_features).