# Using Offline of Open Street Map in my app

Tags: openstreetmap, osmdroid

I already import open street map Library(link of [GitHub](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack)) in my application  and it works completely true but i want to have this map in offline mode(when internet connection is not available user can work with the map).
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794705/open-street-map-working-offline-android)  but i couldn't get it.
please help me ,
thank you for your time.

Comment: Please mention the name of the library.

Comment: sorry , I used of this link :  https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack

Comment: So you are using osmdroid + osmbonuspack.

Comment: yes , I am using osmdroid + osmbonuspack

Answer (score 1):

First of all, welcome to osmdroid.

There's a wealth of documentation on the wiki at https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki

In fact, there's a whole article on offline maps at 
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Offline-Map-Tiles

If those don't answer your question, see the sample app at https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/tree/master/OpenStreetMapViewer

Which has some examples for offline maps.

Comment: I need to have my country map for offline mode . I used of MOBAC for creating my Country map but MOBAC doesn't allow me creat  huge map and mapnik and mapquest are locked ! How can i have my ountry map ? 
Thank you

Comment: Hack it. It's all open source