# Creat an offline map like maps.me application

Tags: openstreetmap, osmdroid

I already import open street map Library([link of GitHub](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack)) in my application and it works completely (I used osmdroid + osmbonuspack)true , but i need to have my country map for offline mode . I used of mobile atlas creator for creating my Country map but mobile atlas creator doesn't allow me creating  huge map.
What i have to do ? I want to have maps like [maps.me](http://maps.me/en/home) in my application
please help me , I am working at this more than 2 weeks .

Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason why you asked the question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546282/using-offline-of-open-street-map-in-my-app/39550718

Answer (score 2):

I used the `osmdroid-forge-app` sample app from https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/ as a starting point and downloaded the offline map files for my country from http://download.mapsforge.org/maps/ .

That worked for me out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

maps.me very likely uses [vector maps](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles) instead of [raster tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles).

Take a look at [Mapsforge](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge) or [Mapbox Android SDK / Mapbox GL](https://www.mapbox.com/maps/) for vector map solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Make more than one map archive or hack up Mobac to remove the limit